Updating an object in the database fails with: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'
I am trying to update an existing BusinessPartner from the database, but it fails with

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException"

I added:
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Version { get; set; } // optimistic concurrency

I wrote down the relevant code:
DBCOntext:
   public class DbTestingCSharp : DbContext
   { 
       public DbSet<BusinessPartner> BusinessPartners { get; set; }
       public DbSet<BPLayerXScraper> BPLayerXScrapers { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       }

       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=...;Database=...;...;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
       }

       public DbTestingCSharp()
       {

       }

       // DI? Auf jeden Fall in Controller
       public DbTestingCSharp(DbContextOptions<DbTestingCSharp> options) : base(options)
       {

       }

   }
    

Data structure
public class BusinessPartner
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    private string _name = String.Empty;
    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value.Length > 200 ? value.Substring(0, 200) : value; }
    }

    public EProductLifeCycleTyp EProductLifeCycle { get; set; } = EProductLifeCycleTyp.None;
    public ESource ESource { get; set; }
    public EBusinessPartner EBusinessPartner { get; set; }
    public string BusinessScope { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string CommercialRegisterNumber { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Website { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public virtual List<BPLayerXScraper> BPLayerXScrapers { get; set; } = new List<BPLayerXScraper>();

    [Required]
    public DateTime TimeStampCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime? TimeStampUpdated { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; } // optimistic concurrency
}

public class BPLayerXScraper
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    //Hash-value, if something changed? Naja, kann ich ja machen schadet ja nicht
    public string Hash { get; set; }

    public int LinksOnTheLandingPage { get; set; }

    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }

    public int Layer { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> Links { get; set; } = new List<string>();


    [Required]
    public DateTime TimeStampCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime? TimeStampUpdated { get; set; }


    public BPLayerXScraper()
    {

    }

    public BPLayerXScraper(string websiteUrl)
    {
        URL = websiteUrl; 
    }

}

Try to update an existing object:
try
 {
     var businessPartner = dbTarget.BusinessPartners
            .Include(bp => bp.BPLayerXScrapers)
            .FirstOrDefault(bp => bp.Name == name);
 
     if (businessPartner == null)
     {
         throw new KeyNotFoundException("BusinessPartner not found.");
     }

     if (businessPartner == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("BusinessPartner not found.");
         return; // Or handle the absence of BusinessPartner accordingly
     }

     BPLayerXScraper newScraper = new BPLayerXScraper
     {
         Hash = "abc123",
         LinksOnTheLandingPage = 10,
         Heading = "Fantasy Heading",
         Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
         URL = "https://example.com",
         Layer = 3,
         Links = new List<string> { "https://example.com/link1", "https://example.com/link2" },
         TimeStampCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
         TimeStampUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
     };

     // Adding the new scraper to the BusinessPartner's collection of scrapers
     businessPartner.BPLayerXScrapers.Add(newScraper);

     // Saving changes in the database
     dbTarget.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("A concurrency conflict occurred. Handling...");

     // Handling concurrency exception specifically for updates to BPLayerXScrapers or BusinessPartner
     foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
     {
         var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
         if (databaseValues != null)
         {
             entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
         }
         else
         {
             // It hits here, even the object is presented in the database
             Console.WriteLine("The object was deleted from the database."); 
         }
     }

     dbTarget.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {e.Message}");
 }
 

It fails with:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'The
database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since
entities were loaded. See
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

Logging:

dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.184 CoreEventId.SaveChangesStarting[10004] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
SaveChanges starting for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.187 CoreEventId.DetectChangesStarting[10800] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
DetectChanges starting for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.205 CoreEventId.CollectionChangeDetected[10804] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
1 entities were added and 0 entities were removed from navigation 'BusinessPartner.BPLayerXScrapers'. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.231 CoreEventId.ForeignKeyChangeDetected[10803] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
The foreign key property 'BPLayerXScraper.BusinessPartnerId' was detected as changed. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see property values.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.237 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
Context 'DbTestingCSharp' started tracking 'BPLayerXScraper' entity. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.240 CoreEventId.DetectChangesCompleted[10801] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
DetectChanges completed for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.273 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpening[20000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opening connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.275 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpened[20001] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opened connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.277 RelationalEventId.CommandCreating[20103] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.279 RelationalEventId.CommandCreated[20104] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (1ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.280 RelationalEventId.CommandInitialized[20106] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Initialized DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (2ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.282 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p9='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p8='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0, [Hash] = @p1, [Heading] = @p2, [Layer] = @p3, [LinksOnTheLandingPage] = @p4, [Text] = @p5, [TimeStampCreated] = @p6, [TimeStampUpdated] = @p7, [URL] = @p8
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p9;
info: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.301 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[@p9='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p8='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0, [Hash] = @p1, [Heading] = @p2, [Layer] = @p3, [LinksOnTheLandingPage] = @p4, [Text] = @p5, [TimeStampCreated] = @p6, [TimeStampUpdated] = @p7, [URL] = @p8
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p9;
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.309 CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException[10006] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.312 RelationalEventId.DataReaderClosing[20301] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Closing data reader to 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.313 RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
A data reader for 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' is being disposed after spending 10ms reading results.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.315 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosing[20002] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closing connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.316 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosed[20003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closed connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' (1ms).
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.337 CoreEventId.QueryCompilationStarting[10111] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query)
Compiling query expression:
'DbSet()
.AsNoTracking()
.IgnoreQueryFilters()
.Where(e => object.Equals(
objA: EF.Property(e, "Id"),
objB: __get_Item_0))
.Select(e => new object[]
{
(object)(Guid)EF.Property(e, "Id"),
(object)(Guid?)EF.Property<Guid?>(e, "BusinessPartnerId"),
(object)(string)EF.Property(e, "Hash"),
(object)(string)EF.Property(e, "Heading"),
(object)(int)EF.Property(e, "Layer"),
(object)(int)EF.Property(e, "LinksOnTheLandingPage"),
(object)(string)EF.Property(e, "Text"),
(object)(DateTime)EF.Property(e, "TimeStampCreated"),
(object)(DateTime?)EF.Property<DateTime?>(e, "TimeStampUpdated"),
(object)(string)EF.Property(e, "URL")
})
.FirstOrDefault()'
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.345 CoreEventId.QueryExecutionPlanned[10107] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query)
Generated query execution expression:
'queryContext => new SingleQueryingEnumerable<object[]>(
(RelationalQueryContext)queryContext,
RelationalCommandCache.QueryExpression(
Client Projections:
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 5
6 -> 6
7 -> 7
8 -> 8
9 -> 9
SELECT TOP(1) b.Id, b.BusinessPartnerId, b.Hash, b.Heading, b.Layer, b.LinksOnTheLandingPage, b.Text, b.TimeStampCreated, b.TimeStampUpdated, b.URL
FROM BPLayerXScrapers AS b
WHERE b.Id == @__get_Item_0),
null,
Func<QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator, object[]>,
DbTesting.DbTestingCSharp,
False,
False,
True
)
.SingleOrDefault()'
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.348 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpening[20000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opening connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.349 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpened[20001] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opened connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.351 RelationalEventId.CommandCreating[20103] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.353 RelationalEventId.CommandCreated[20104] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (1ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.354 RelationalEventId.CommandInitialized[20106] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Initialized DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (3ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.355 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [b].[Id], [b].[BusinessPartnerId], [b].[Hash], [b].[Heading], [b].[Layer], [b].[LinksOnTheLandingPage], [b].[Text], [b].[TimeStampCreated], [b].[TimeStampUpdated], [b].[URL]
FROM [BPLayerXScrapers] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
info: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.359 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [b].[Id], [b].[BusinessPartnerId], [b].[Hash], [b].[Heading], [b].[Layer], [b].[LinksOnTheLandingPage], [b].[Text], [b].[TimeStampCreated], [b].[TimeStampUpdated], [b].[URL]
FROM [BPLayerXScrapers] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.360 RelationalEventId.DataReaderClosing[20301] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Closing data reader to 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.361 RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
A data reader for 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' is being disposed after spending 1ms reading results.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.362 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosing[20002] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closing connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.364 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosed[20003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closed connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' (1ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.365 CoreEventId.SaveChangesStarting[10004] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
SaveChanges starting for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.366 CoreEventId.DetectChangesStarting[10800] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
DetectChanges starting for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.369 CoreEventId.DetectChangesCompleted[10801] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
DetectChanges completed for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.371 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpening[20000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opening connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.373 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpened[20001] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opened connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.374 RelationalEventId.CommandCreating[20103] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.375 RelationalEventId.CommandCreated[20104] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (1ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.376 RelationalEventId.CommandInitialized[20106] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Initialized DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (2ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.377 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p9='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p8='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0, [Hash] = @p1, [Heading] = @p2, [Layer] = @p3, [LinksOnTheLandingPage] = @p4, [Text] = @p5, [TimeStampCreated] = @p6, [TimeStampUpdated] = @p7, [URL] = @p8
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p9;
info: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.379 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p9='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 4000), @p6='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p8='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0, [Hash] = @p1, [Heading] = @p2, [Layer] = @p3, [LinksOnTheLandingPage] = @p4, [Text] = @p5, [TimeStampCreated] = @p6, [TimeStampUpdated] = @p7, [URL] = @p8
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p9;
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.381 CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException[10006] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.383 RelationalEventId.DataReaderClosing[20301] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Closing data reader to 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.384 RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
A data reader for 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' is being disposed after spending 2ms reading results.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.385 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosing[20002] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closing connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:29:06.386 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosed[20003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closed connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' (1ms).
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Sensitive Logging:

dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.145 CoreEventId.SaveChangesStarting[10004] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
SaveChanges starting for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.148 CoreEventId.DetectChangesStarting[10800] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
DetectChanges starting for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.165 CoreEventId.CollectionChangeDetected[10804] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
1 entities were added and 0 entities were removed from navigation 'BusinessPartner.BPLayerXScrapers' on entity with key '{Id: f7e9aec7-c04c-41e2-aad1-b1283536c32e}'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.192 CoreEventId.ForeignKeyChangeDetected[10803] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
The foreign key property 'BPLayerXScraper.BusinessPartnerId' was detected as changed from '(null)' to 'f7e9aec7-c04c-41e2-aad1-b1283536c32e' for entity with key '{Id: ab313081-5c02-4e60-98b2-bc651ba737fd}'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.198 CoreEventId.StartedTracking[10806] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
Context 'DbTestingCSharp' started tracking 'BPLayerXScraper' entity with key '{Id: ab313081-5c02-4e60-98b2-bc651ba737fd}'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.200 CoreEventId.DetectChangesCompleted[10801] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking)
DetectChanges completed for 'DbTestingCSharp'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.236 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpening[20000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opening connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.239 RelationalEventId.ConnectionOpened[20001] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Opened connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.241 RelationalEventId.CommandCreating[20103] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.242 RelationalEventId.CommandCreated[20104] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (1ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.244 RelationalEventId.CommandInitialized[20106] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Initialized DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (3ms).
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.247 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p9='ab313081-5c02-4e60-98b2-bc651ba737fd', @p0='f7e9aec7-c04c-41e2-aad1-b1283536c32e' (Nullable = true), @p1='abc123' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p2='Fantasy Heading' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p3='3', @p4='10', @p5='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p6='2024-04-20T07:36:31.9677616Z', @p7='2024-04-21T07:36:31.9677827Z' (Nullable = true), @p8='https://example.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0, [Hash] = @p1, [Heading] = @p2, [Layer] = @p3, [LinksOnTheLandingPage] = @p4, [Text] = @p5, [TimeStampCreated] = @p6, [TimeStampUpdated] = @p7, [URL] = @p8
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p9;
info: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.256 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@p9='ab313081-5c02-4e60-98b2-bc651ba737fd', @p0='f7e9aec7-c04c-41e2-aad1-b1283536c32e' (Nullable = true), @p1='abc123' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p2='Fantasy Heading' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p3='3', @p4='10', @p5='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000), @p6='2024-04-20T07:36:31.9677616Z', @p7='2024-04-21T07:36:31.9677827Z' (Nullable = true), @p8='https://example.com' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0, [Hash] = @p1, [Heading] = @p2, [Layer] = @p3, [LinksOnTheLandingPage] = @p4, [Text] = @p5, [TimeStampCreated] = @p6, [TimeStampUpdated] = @p7, [URL] = @p8
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p9;
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.263 CoreEventId.OptimisticConcurrencyException[10006] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.266 RelationalEventId.DataReaderClosing[20301] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Closing data reader to 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.268 RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
A data reader for 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' is being disposed after spending 9ms reading results.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.270 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosing[20002] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closing connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx'.
dbug: 20.04.2024 09:36:45.271 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosed[20003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
Closed connection to database 'xTesting' on server 'xxxx' (1ms).
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll

What should I change, how?

What line exactly is that exception occurring?  When you first try saving the record with the new item or when you try handling a concurrency exception and saving changes inside the catch block? I don't think that catch block will work as the DbContext is poisoned at that point, and you're trying to set  original values when it will be the modified values that will cause the issue. I can see a few things wrong with your entity such as setting the  PK in code rather than using an identity column, setters on the version and collection navigation property that should be tied down.

What SQL EF Core tries to execute? Enable logging for EF if it's not already (for example - simple one)

Hi @StevePy the error occurs at dbTarget.SaveChanges()

Hi @GuruStron I inserted the logs

The following:
UPDATE [BPLayerXScrapers] SET [BusinessPartnerId] = @p0,
...

Means that EF tries to update the BPLayerXScraper entity instead of inserting a newly created one. By default EF assumes that ids are database generated. From the EF Core: Keys docs:

Value generation
For non-composite numeric and GUID primary keys, EF Core sets up value generation for you by convention. For example, a numeric primary key in SQL Server is automatically set up to be an IDENTITY column. For more information, see the documentation on value generation and guidance for specific inheritance mapping strategies.

The non-default value of entity key seems to confuse the EF, so try removing  = Guid.NewGuid(); from public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid(); in BPLayerXScraper.
Or if you want to assign the key client side you can try disabling the generation:
public class BPLayerXScraper
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    // ...
}

